# eslint no-use-before-define rules does not work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I use node.js 12.3.0 and i had installed eslint 7.0.0 by npm.
So i wrote the .eslintrc.js like below.

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always", {"omitLastInOneLineBlock": true }],
        "no-shadow-restricted-names" : "error",
        "no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "vars": "all" }],
        "no-redeclare": ["error", { "builtinGlobals": true }],
        "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": true, "classes": true, "variables": true }]
    }
};
```

As you know, i already added  "no-use-before-define" but it didn't work.
All another eslint rules are worked fine but only "no-use-before-define" didn't check anythings.

Here is my examples js file.

```
let c = qwertqwert(); //As you know qwerqwert is not defined. I want to check this.
a = 123123; //I don't want to allow assign any value to variable before declaration.
b = asdfafasfdasdfas; //Also i need to check any undefined variable or functions are used.
```

Does "no-use-before-define" can check this?

It seems only can check when i use the variable or function before define or declaration.

```
Func(); //I use(call) first.

//But the define statement is after.
function Func()
{
   return 10;
}
```

Above code had checked fine by eslint but it is meaningless.
Because i want let eslint to check usage of undefined functions or value.

Comment: The rule you need is [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).

Comment: @GOTO0 You R my hero~ lol....

Answer (score 1):

if you define eslint should show the error you should write a rule like

- if you don't want rule you can remove it or skip rule by file

  ```
   "no-use-before-define": [
       "error",
       {
           "functions": false,
           "classes": false,
           "variables": false
       }
   ],
  ```

NOTE :- i am using extension of airbnb

```
 extends: [
'airbnb-base',
```

],

it works for me

node js :- 14.17.6

eslint :- 7.12.1+

[image]

and if function is not defined then it shows

[image]

Comment: the error is "function fun(): number
'fun' was used before it was defined.eslintno-use-before-define
"

Comment: Thanks for answering. But as i already said, it does not shows error if the fun() function does not defined anywhere. It just shows error when i define function after call function.

Comment: @HelloWorld it shows error if the function does not defined anywhere,
added not defined screenshot as well